# USB Debugging issue on Android after rooting up my phone: "CreateJavaVM failed: dvmGcStartup failed"

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I was working on Android Platform and I use my HTC Sensation for checking whatever I have developed directly on my phone via USB debugging instead of using that heavy emulator and everything was working perfect. But last week I rooted my phone and installed some custom ROM. After this problem arises that now when I connect my phone Eclipse does recognize it but when I run the developed app on eclipse it doesn't load on the phone.

USB debugging is enabled on phone.

Can you please tell me what is the problem ?

Here is the error I get in the LogCat but I dunno what it is:

[image]

Comment: What is the ROM you are using actually?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is all your ROM's mistake. A little bug in your ROM. I advise you to change to a new ROM. Most probably it will get rid of this error.

Comment: Yup, try re-flashing your ROM.